# Use cell next to another cell

Tags: excel, dynamic, average

I have a file containing various sheets and I need an average of the values in those sheets. It looks as follows:

```
06:45     to    06:50   15
06:50     to    06:55   18
06:55     to    07:00   20
07:00     to    07:05   27
07:05     to    07:10   14
07:10     to    07:15   16
07:15     to    07:20   18
07:20     to    07:25   16
07:25     to    07:30   14
```

This is system generated data and reflects the number of people spent the defined time at the parking lot. For example: `07:25 to 07:30 14` reflects how many people (14) stayed from 7 hours and 25 minutes to 7:30 minutes inside the parking lot that month, in this case January.

The problem is that when the number of people is 0, the minutes don't appear, so using a formula that makes an average of cells 526 in every sheet for example wouldn't work because the minutes wouldn't be the same. What I am thinking is to something like telling excel to use the value in the cell next to "07:25 to 07:30" in every sheet and then make an average.

It seems to be a simple issue but I tried searching all over the web for it and couldn't help myself. If anyone has any idea, please share. VBA is possible but I don´t know how to work with it so simple formulas would be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm hearing that you want the average number of people parked across an entire day's worth of 5 minute time spans.

You could do a couple things, one, don't use the average function.  Instead, because you know there are (24*60)/5 = 288 separate 5 minute intervals in the day, you should just sum all of the people, then divide by 288.

If you have an entire months of rows (288*31 days in Jan), then divide by that number.

Perhaps it would help if you explain what is in each sheet?
Also if you can clarify what you're averaging across? Days/months/parking lots?

Note: this may be better suited to https://superuser.com/